# Load report failed

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I created one application in C# .Net for viewing crystal report. But when I tried to execute it, it showed:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'CrystalDecisions.Shared.CrystalReportsException' occurred in
>   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll
>       Additional information: Load report failed..

This is what I have tried:

```
connect();
sql = "select INVOICE.[InvoiceNo], [InvoiceDate],[CustId],Subtotal,Pid,Qty ,Rate,amount from INVOICE inner join invoicedetails on INVOICE.[InvoiceNO]= invoicedetails.[InvoicoNo] where invoicedetails.[InvoicoNo] = '" + INVID+ "' ";
objcmd = new SqlCommand(sql, objcon);
objda.SelectCommand = objcmd;
Mydataset.Clear();
objda.Fill(Mydataset "dis");
path.Load(Application.StartupPath + "C:\\Report_InvoiceRPT.rpt");
path.SetDataSource(Mydataset.Tables["dis"]);
crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = path;
crystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

The following is the line that is giving me the error:

```
path.Load(Application.StartupPath + "C:\\Report_InvoiceRPT.rpt");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of path are you expecting to have with `Application.StartupPath + "C:\\Report_InvoiceRPT.rpt"`? 
This path does not exist. You are concatenating the application startup path with hard coded file path `C:\\Report_InvoiceRPT.rpt`.

Always use `Path.Combine()` to combine two string paths. This way you avoid double path separators since `Path.Combine()` checks whether the first path has already a separator at the end so it will not duplicate the separators. Additionally, it checks whether the path elements to combine have invalid characters.

An additional check `File.Exists()` would only make your application more robust.